# What to check after a linux server crashes?

Tags: debian-lenny, failed

My linux server (debian 5) stalled and had to be rebooted.

Please advise what to check in order to find out what happened. Usual suspects like `/var/log/messages`, `syslog`, and `kern.log`. Could you give me only a hint that load average skyrocketed to over 100 before failure? Don't know where to look further.

Comment: After server fault, check stack overflow.  (Sorry, sorry.)

Comment: Please give more information about that server hard/soft configuration and services.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to give more information about your server configuration, and post those logs. How do you know that the load average got high ?

**The "load average skyrocketing to over 100 before failure" symptom can have many causes, but there are frequent ones.**

**First, what is the load average ?**

I recommend looking at this post to get more information on the subject : https://superuser.com/questions/23498/what-does-load-average-mean-in-unix-linux

The load average is an indicator of how many processes are currently in the "waiting" state. A very high load average indicates ressource exhaustion, and a common cause of this ressource exhaustion is long (or infinite) waiting times for I/O operations to complete.

**What could cause this ?**

- I/O Waiting can be because of a failing NFS mount, of a failing hard
  disk drive. You may have been the victim of an attack.
- Attacks like
  [Slowloris](http://ha.ckers.org/slowloris/) tend to exhaust the file
  handle pool, and can hang I/O operations on the server.
- Pay attention
  to fork bombs too. If you suffered a fork bomb, and that your memory
  got exhausted, you may see traces about the "OOM Killer", a kernel
  worker that sacrifices processes to free up memory for the system
  when everything else have failed. On some setups, that OOM Killer can
  make the system reboot.

**Where to look ?**

This really depends on your system configuration and environment. **You did not provide enough details in your question** to answer to this particular question. Here are some ideas, though :

- First, check all of your hard drives. Run full SMART tests on them.
- If you have hardware RAID, check your RAID controller's log.
- If you are hosting web services, check for bandwidth usage history, and requests count.
- If you have remote network mounts (sshfs, NFS), check their reliability
- If you are hosting user shells on your server, check their .bash_history (**This can be faked.**)
- If that server is a virtual machine, the problem may have nothing to do with your server but with your virtual services provider.